# Should I register a model observer in a service provider or in Model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

There are 2 ways to register a model observer -

Approach 1: AppServiceProvider

```php
public function boot()
{
    CourseTag::observe(CourseTagObserver::class);
}
```

Approach 2: Model itself

```php
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    parent::observe(new CourseTagObserver);
}
```

I am not sure when to use approach 1 and when to use approach 2 ??

Comment: Your second example is registering a relation, not an observer.

Comment: @atymic Sorry, my mistake. now i have updated the code. please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd generally go with the method outlined in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers), but either way will work fine. It's up to your personal preference.

> To register an observer, use the observe method on the model you wish to observe. You may register observers in the boot method of one of your service providers. In this example, we'll register the observer in the AppServiceProvider:

```php
public function boot()
{
    User::observe(UserObserver::class);
}
```

Comment: What about the second approach?